# c# close ie tab based on knowing process ID

Tags: c#, process, hwnd

so adding improvements to existing code. Right now its opening up IE windows to nav to certain sites

```
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = Configuration.IExplorerLocation();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = url;

        // Start the process with the info we specified.

        Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

so now the client wants us to close that window if they attempt to click on that same nav button in the UI. So I need to hold something, to go an close that later if they attempt again. I have saved off the handle, the process id etc to attempt to close later but it seems to then have no clue that window exists. I think part of my issue might be that IE kinda has a main PID and any new windows get new PID's but I save off the PID I jsut created and 50ms later it doesnt know it exists to close it.. using this code

```
                    log.Info(fn + "parse -" + _iNypIEProcessIdName);
                string[] ProcData = _iNypIEProcessIdName.Split('-');
                int ProcId = 0;
                log.Info(fn + " "+ ProcData[0]);
                Int32.TryParse(ProcData[0], out ProcId);
                //Process exeProcess as new Process;
                Process CheckProcess = null;
                log.Info(fn + "2");
                try
                {
                    CheckProcess = Process.GetProcessById(ProcId);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.Error(fn + " iNYP process not found to remove ", e);
                }
                if (CheckProcess.ProcessName == ProcData[1])
                {
                    // then I think we have a match ??
                    log.Debug(fn + " Attempting to close ID" + ProcId + " " + ProcData[1]);
                    CheckProcess.Close();
                }
```

so not sure if just my code is wrong...  but I guess I'm more looking for a good way to open a process... get some info on it that I can later use to close it if they attempt to NAV to pretty much the same URL. Should I just loop through all existing IE windows and find the same URL and close ? I just figured trying to get the handle or the PID would be cleaner.. and side note when I try to get the handle after the process starts the window is not fully up and the handle is ZERO.. so any advice is welcome !!!

Comment: It is much easier to achieve this sort of thing through MS UI Automation library

Comment: are you saying after the fact with what I'm doing .. or right from the bat we should have used that class to call the process.. I assume the later. I was not sure why they did a process call and not use the IE class to drive it up. This code was written before I got this dumped on me.